# Lightning Scheduler - Review Service Appointment Screen Issue

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, field-service-lightning, lightning-scheduler

"Parent Record" field display blank value in Review Service Appointment screen (Salesforce Lightning Scheduler). Below are the steps:

1. Added flow (**Outbound New Appointment**) action in Work Order object. This flow is part of "Salesforce Lightning Scheduler license".
2. While creating new Service Appointment from Work Order record layout using above action, I see parent record gets populated as expected under "Select Service Resources" screen.
3. Fast forward with further screens and value selection by click 'Next'. When you reach "Review Service Appointment" screen, parent record displays blank value (empty) and I expect Work Order Number to be displayed as shown in first screenshot (refer yellow highlight). **This is my issue.**

I tried different options but Parent Record displays empty value in "Review Service Appointment" screen. Did anyone face similar issue and fixed it or any help here would be appreciated.

Note: From Yesterday, I'm getting additional popup error like below when click action button. Not sure if this anything to do with Winter release that went recently.
[image]

Added More Information:

1. Flow Name: Outbound New Appointment. I can see parent record populated in “Attendees Screen”. Refer below screenshots.
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
2. Refer “Review Screen” below and more screenshots, where Parent Record value is blank or null.
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Developer Console (F12) or Apex Debug Logs? If you can find any extra info, that would greatly help us.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @sfdcfox - There is no errors in Developer Console or Apex logs. When i enable this action in Account Layout passing Account Id as parent record, it displays as expected in "Review Service Appointment" screen. This popup error and parent record being null happens only when i add an action in "Work Order" object.

Comment: @Community - I have updated description to make it more clear. Parent Record is blank when I navigate to "Review Service Appiontment" screen while creating Service Appointment through Work Order object. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I've never done anything with Work Orders or Lightning Schedule....; (1) Is **Outbound New Appointment** an OOTB Action that you activated, something you created, or something you installed? (2) Please share more screenshots of your Flow - at least from the step that first retrieves or uses the "Parent Record" all the way to the step where the "Parent Record" does not show.

Comment: @Moonpie - Yes, Outbound New Appointment is an OOTB Flow in Field Service Lightning (Lightning Scheduler).

Comment: @Moonpie - Added more information with screeenshots.